# Manejar mismatched type del tipo []String,bson y time.time en golang

Tags: go

Buenas tardes compañeros, vengo con la siguiente pregunta estoy desarrollando en un framework Iris y me he encontrado con el siguiente problema, la manipúlacion  de tipos de datos 
 mi codigo es el siguiente :

```
//ExpresionRegularMgo estructura de ExpresionRegulars mongo
type ExpresionRegularMgo struct {
    ID        bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Id        string        `bson:"ID"`
    Nombre    string        `bson:"Nombre"`
    Expresion string        `bson:"Expresion"`
    Etiquetas []string      `bson:"Etiquetas"`
    Estatus   bson.ObjectId `bson:"Estatus"`
    FechaHora time.Time     `bson:"FechaHora"`
}

//ExpresionRegularElastic estructura de ExpresionRegulars para insertar en Elastic
type ExpresionRegularElastic struct {
    Id        string        `json:"ID"`
    Nombre    string        `json:"Nombre"`
    Expresion string        `json:"Expresion"`
    Etiquetas []string      `json:"Etiquetas"`
    Estatus   bson.ObjectId `json:"Estatus"`
    FechaHora time.Time     `json:"FechaHora"`
}
```

al momento de concatenar los strings tengo problema en los tipos []string, bson.ObjectId y time.Time, los estoy concatenado de tal forma que se muestren en mi página de la siguiente manera

```
func GeneraTemplatesBusqueda(ExpresionRegulars []ExpresionRegularMgo) (string, string) {
    floats := accounting.Accounting{Symbol: "", Precision: 2}
    cuerpo := ``

    cabecera := `<tr>
            <th>#</th>

                <th>Id</th>                 

                <th>Nombre</th>                 

                <th>Expresion</th>                  

                <th>Etiquetas</th>                  

                <th>Estatus</th>                    

                <th>FechaHora</th>                  
                </tr>`

    for k, v := range ExpresionRegulars {
        cuerpo += `<tr id = "` + v.ID.Hex() + `" onclick="window.location.href = '/ExpresionRegulars/detalle/` + v.ID.Hex() + `';">`
        cuerpo += `<td>` + strconv.Itoa(k+1) + `</td>`
        cuerpo += `<td>` + v.Id + `</td>`

        cuerpo += `<td>` + v.Nombre + `</td>`

        cuerpo += `<td>` + v.Expresion + `</td>`

        cuerpo += `<td>` + v.Etiquetas + `</td>`

        cuerpo += `<td>` + v.Estatus + `</td>`

        cuerpo += `<td>` + v.FechaHora + `</td>`

        cuerpo += `</tr>`
    }

    return cabecera, cuerpo
}
```

sin embargo tengo problemas en cuanto al manejo de tipos en v.Etiquetas, V.Estatus y v.FechaHora ¿cual podria ser la forma para concatener esos objetos en la salida a mostrar del html?

Gracias de antemano y saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer esto de forma correcta, seria mejor emplear el fmt (paquete formateador) que permite exactamente lo que estas intentando. La función que debes emplear es la fmt.Sprintf, donde el primer parámetro es la string que quieras introducir con %v donde vayan los parámetros de la base de datos Mongo y despues son los parámetros separados por coma

```
func GeneraTemplatesBusqueda(ExpresionRegulars []ExpresionRegularMgo) (string, string) {
//floats := accounting.Accounting{Symbol: "", Precision: 2}
cuerpo := ``

cabecera := `<tr>
        <th>#</th>

            <th>Id</th>                 

            <th>Nombre</th>                 

            <th>Expresion</th>                  

            <th>Etiquetas</th>                  

            <th>Estatus</th>                    

            <th>FechaHora</th>                  
            </tr>`

for k, v := range ExpresionRegulars {
    cuerpo += fmt.Sprintf(`<tr id = "%v" onclick="window.location.href = '/ExpresionRegulars/detalle/%v';">`, v.ID.Hex(), v.ID.Hex())
    cuerpo += fmt.Sprintf(`<td> %v </td>`, k+1)
    cuerpo += fmt.Sprintf(`<td> %v </td>`, v.Id)
    cuerpo += fmt.Sprintf(`<td> %v </td>`, v.Nombre)
    cuerpo += fmt.Sprintf(`<td> %v </td>`, v.Expression)
    cuerpo += fmt.Sprintf(`<td> %v </td>`, v.Etiquetas)
    cuerpo += fmt.Sprintf(`<td> %v </td>`, v.Estatus)
    cuerpo += fmt.Sprintf(`<td> %v </td>`, v.FechaHora)
    cuerpo += `</tr>`
}
```